# Handle Pagination for both Disk Cache and Network with RxJava

Tags: android, pagination, rx-java

Is there any good pattern using RxJava to handle pagination for both Offline and Online. Currently, I'm using this pattern and the code looks dirty. What I want to do is Page 1 Offline => Page 1 Online => Page 2 Offline => Page 2 Online..etc. until the end of pages. Every offline call would add to the list where Online calls will update the item in the page.

```
  public void loadData() {
    paginator = PublishSubject.create();
    paginator.concatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<Response>>() {
      @Override public ObservableSource<Response> apply(Integer integer)
          throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request();
        request.page = integer;
        return NetworkRequestManager.getInstance()
            .getData(request)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
      }
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new ResponseSubscriber());

    mEndlessRecyclerAdapter.onDataReady(true);
  }
```

In The NetWorkRequestManager class, I'm using the following code

```
  public Observable<Response> getData(final Request request) {

    return dataService.getOnlineData(request)
        .publish(networkResponse ->  Observable.merge(networkResponse, dataService.getOfflineData(request).takeUntil(networkResponse)));
  }
```

And when data loading is success.

```
 @Subscribe public void onDataLoaded(Response response) {

    if (response.getCurrentPage() == 1) {
      mAdapter.setItemList(items);
    } else if (!response.data.isEmpty()) {
      if (response.isFromOffline) {
        mAdapter.addItemList(response.data);
        wasOfflineEmpty = false;
      } else if (wasOfflineEmpty) {
        mAdapter.addItemList(response.data);
      } else {
        mAdapter.updateItemList(response.data);
      }
    } else if (response.data.isEmpty() && response.isFromOffline) {
      wasOfflineEmpty = true;
    }
    mEndlessRecyclerAdapter.onDataReady(response.data.size() != 0);
  }
```

As you can see, there's a lot boilerplate in OnDataLoaded method. Is there any better or recommended way to reduce boilerplate?

Comment: Did you find a clean solution to this?

Comment: am finding difficulty with same any solution?